# Mysql month number to month name conversion

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, oracle-sqldeveloper, azure-mysql-database

I have month value like "22018" in my column I need it like Feb-2018 in mysql workbench

Comment: What's the column data type?

Comment: nah just change your data type to varchar so that you can store something like that but this will slows down your searching, perhaps I suggest you to seperate them in 2 columns year and month that you can filter them in future for searching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first extract the month from the date (considering it will have one or two digits), e.g.:

```
SELECT LPAD(SUBSTRING('22018', 1, LENGTH('22018') - 4), 2, '0');
```

This will give you `02`. Now, you can extract the year with similar logic, e.g.:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('22018', LENGTH('22018') - 4 + 1, LENGTH('22018'));
```

Finally, you can concatenate all these to get a string like `2018-02-01`:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING('22018', LENGTH('22018') - 4 + 1, LENGTH('22018')),
'-',
LPAD(SUBSTRING('22018', 1, LENGTH('22018') - 4), 2, '0'), '-01');
```

Once this is done, you can use `DATE_FORMAT` function to get the required output:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING('22018', LENGTH('22018') - 4 + 1, 
LENGTH('22018')),
'-',
LPAD(SUBSTRING('22018', 1, LENGTH('22018') - 4), 2, '0'), '-01'), '%M-%Y');
```